# Rows into Columns in t-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
ID  ColumnName
1   START_DTTM
1   END_DTTM
1   STATUS
2   START_DTTM
2   END_DTTM
2   status
3   START_DTTM
3   END_DTTM
3   status
3   Archive
```

I want result like this:

```
ID  ColumnName      ColumnName2     ColumnName3     ColumnName4 
1   START_DTTM      END_DTTM        status          NULL
2   START_DTTM      END_DTTM        status          NULL
3   START_DTTM      END_DTTM        status          Archive
```

Any help..Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use PIVOT option in SQL.

Comment: I tried with PIVOT, but I am confusing with aggregate function in PIVOT. Can you please provide sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This produces the wanted result. But please be aware, that there is **no implicit sort order**! Without a specific `ORDER BY` you might get random result.

```
declare @tbl TABLE(ID INT,  ColumnName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'START_DTTM')
,(1,'END_DTTM')
,(1,'STATUS')
,(2,'START_DTTM')
,(2,'END_DTTM')
,(2,'status')
,(3,'START_DTTM')
,(3,'END_DTTM')
,(3,'status')
,(3,'Archive');


SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 'ColumnName' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS PivotColumn
          ,tbl.*
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS x
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ColumnName) FOR PivotColumn IN(ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3,ColumnName4)
) AS p
```

The result:

```
ID  ColumnName1 ColumnName2 ColumnName3 ColumnName4
1   START_DTTM  END_DTTM    STATUS      NULL
2   START_DTTM  END_DTTM    status      NULL
3   START_DTTM  END_DTTM    status      Archive
```

Comment: You are Star mate, Thanks. Can you please explain `MIN(ColumnName)` in `PIVOT`

Comment: @user3583912, That's easy: PIVOT needs an aggregat. The trick with the column names via partitioned ROW_NUMBER will surely deliver **just one** value so aggregation doesn't make any difference. VARCHAR is sortable and therefore can be used in MIN...

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, Thanks for Explanations.